# Question about the Mathematica Weekly Exchange Newsletters

Tags: support

Are the Mathematica Weekly Exchange Newsletters accessible on this Mathematica.StackExchange.com website somewhere?  Thank you!

Comment: You can subscribe [here](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters).

Comment: @gwr  I think the question is, are back issues available?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Oh, I missed that completely. That is indeed an interesting question, are they?

Answer (score 6):

I found one [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/mathematica_stackexchange_letters/index.htm) it goes back to April 2013

[image: Mathematica graphics]